# Change Style / Font of the Label of a Gtk.Button

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

Environment: Python 3.4.3, GTK+ 3

Hey there,
I am trying to write a Gtk-application with a Gtk.ToggleButton beeing able to change the font of his Label. Here is my example, I would like to make the Label "active", which you get, when clicking the button, to be **strong**.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class TOGGLE_WINDOW:

    def delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        print('delete event occurred')
        return False

    def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Gtk.Window()
        self.window.set_title('Toggle Button Font Change')
        self.window.connect('delete_event', self.delete_event)
        self.window.connect('destroy', self.destroy)

        self.box = Gtk.HBox()
        self.box.set_size_request(400, 50)

        self.toggle = Gtk.ToggleButton(label = 'inactive')
        self.toggle.connect('toggled', self.on_toggled, 'toggle')

        self.box.pack_start(self.toggle, True, True, 0)
        self.window.add(self.box)

        self.window.show_all()

    def on_toggled(self, event, widget):
        state = self.toggle.get_active()

        if state == True:
            self.toggle.set_label('active')
        else:
            self.toggle.set_label('inactive')

    def main(self):
        Gtk.main()

if __name__=='__main__':
    run = TOGGLE_WINDOW()
    run.main()
```

When I try to use an external Gtk.Label to put on the Button Python says:
*TypeError: Must be string, not Label*.
In this case the function looks like this:

```
def on_toggled(self, event, widget):
    state = self.toggle.get_active()

    self.label = Gtk.Label()
    self.label.set_markup('<b>active</b>')

    if state == True:
      self.toggle.set_label(self.label)
    else:
      self.toggle.set_label('inactive')
```

Seems, like the Buttonlabel just accepts strings.
I also thought about converting a text to a picture and put this on the Button, but there should be an easier way...

Thank you for ideas!

Comment: GtkButton's `set_label()` method only accepts strings, but a GtkButton is a GtkBin, so you can get at the label widget with `get_child()`.

Comment: Thank you andlabs, that worked! I'm going to put this in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, thanks to [@andlabs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3408572/andlabs) I got the right code now. 
I can get the label of the Gtk.Button by using get_child() and then use set_markup() with html-like styleconfigurations:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class TOGGLE_WINDOW:

    def delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        print('delete event occurred')
        return False

    def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Gtk.Window()
        self.window.set_title('Toggle Button Font Change')
        self.window.connect('delete_event', self.delete_event)
        self.window.connect('destroy', self.destroy)

        self.box = Gtk.HBox()
        self.box.set_size_request(400, 50)

        self.toggle = Gtk.ToggleButton(label = 'inactive')
        self.toggle.connect('toggled', self.on_toggled, 'toggle')

        self.box.pack_start(self.toggle, True, True, 0)
        self.window.add(self.box)

        self.window.show_all()

    def on_toggled(self, event, widget):
        state = self.toggle.get_active()

        if state == True:
            # here I get the Label and set its markup
            self.label = self.toggle.get_child()
            self.label.set_markup('<b>active</b>')  
        else:
            self.toggle.set_label('inactive')

    def main(self):
        Gtk.main()

if __name__=='__main__':
    run = TOGGLE_WINDOW()
    run.main()
```

Thank you for your fast help!